# How to sort multiple columns using PrimeNG

Tags: angular, sorting, primeng

How can I sort multiple columns while using a `p-table`, PrimeNG | Angular UI Component Library?

```
<h3>Multi Sort Columns</h3>
<p-table
  [columns]="cols"
  [value]="cars1"
  [lazy]="lazy"
  [lazyLoadOnInit]="lazyLoadOnInit"
    (onLazyLoad)="loadList($event)"
  [sortMode]="sortMode"
  [multiSortMeta]="multiSortMeta">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Can there be a default predefined secondary sort column ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned customSort() in  <p-table> tag. How come you are able to call customSort() in typescript?   AND  did you find a way to set predefiend secondary sort. Because multiSortMeta sets the sorting just for first time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define multiple predefined sorts by using `multiSortMeta` property.

Here is an example:

```
[multiSortMeta]="[{field: 'quantity', order: -1}, {field: 'price', order: 1}]"
```

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesort-demo-mvorbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, and demo as well.

Comment: In my case i want to set secondary sort predefined always, not just first time at the page load. multiSortMeta works only for once here.